# Unit Tests with Angularfire2 on angular-cli

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular-cli, angularfire2

Created a new angular 2 project with angular-cli

Below is the default component app.component.ts and it has app.component.spec.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2'; // import angularfire2

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  af: AngularFire;
  constructor(af: AngularFire){
    this.af=af;
    this.firebaseCall();
  }
  //push data to firebase collection
  firebaseCall(){
    let post=this.af.database.list('/post');
    post.push({a:'test'});
  }

}
```

To Implement Unit test for the above **firebaseCall()** in app.component.spec.ts

I have added/updated below lines in app.component.spec.ts

```
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,AngularFire // extra added
      ],

    });
    TestBed.compileComponents();

  });
```

I get below error while ng test

**Unexpected value 'AngularFire' declared by the module 'DynamicTestModule'**

Comment: Have a look at the AngularFire2 source to see how the `TestBed` can be configured: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/2.0.0-beta.8/src/angularfire2.spec.ts#L31-L52

Comment: added this line imports: [AngularFireModule.initializeApp(COMMON_CONFIG)]

getting this error
 Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock the services in the test.
Here you are injecting `AngularFire`. So you test setup should be like this.

```
    import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';
...
   const mockFirebase = jasmine.createSpyObj('af',['database']);
   af.database.and.returnValue({list: Rx.Observable.of([])});   
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [
            AppComponent
          ],
          providers:[
          {provide:AngularFire, useValue:}]
        });
        TestBed.compileComponents();

      });
```

Hope, this helps you. always mock your providers in the unit-test and don't make a http call.